# How to subtract two equations?

Tags: equations, align

I am trying to subtract one equation from another but I can't get it to display the way that I want. This is what I have right now.

```
\begin{align*}
&y&=2x+5\\   
-&&\\    
&y&=3x+10\\\hline   
&0&=-x-5    
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Well, how *do* you want it to display?

Comment: Is this to demonstrate solving linear equations by addition? If so, why not multiply the bottom equation by -1 and present it as addition as you have it: (a la http://www.purplemath.com/modules/systlin5.htm).

Comment: It looks like this began life as an eqnarray. Try loosing the second & on each line just to start with.

Comment: [as done for plus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223341/62865)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This does not look very good but seems close to what your code is attempting to do, where I use `\cline{}` to draw the horizontal line, and `\phantom{y=}` to push the minus sign to the left

[image]

---

### Recomended Solution:

However, I would suggest the use of `\intertext` or `\shortintertext`  from [the `mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), and refer to the equations:

[image]

### Notes:

- Requires two runs: first run will display a `(??)` in the cross reference.
- `\shortintertext` yields better spacing but requires an additional package. Alternatively, you can use `\intertext` which is available in `amsmath`.
- [The `mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) already includes `amsmath`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    y&=2x+5\\   
    -\phantom{y=}&\\    
    y&=3x+10\\
   \cline{1-2}
    0&=-x-5    
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    y&=2x+5 \label{eqn:one}\\
    y&=3x+10 \label{eqn:two}\\
  \shortintertext{Subtracting \eqref{eqn:two} from \eqref{eqn:one} yields}
    0&=-x-5  \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The recommended version is indeed much better in my opinion. A small nitpick: `\eqref` might be better to make a distinction between numbers and equations.

Comment: Seeing your recommended version, I think that it is a better approach.

Comment: @percusse: Thanks for pointing that out. Have updated the solution to correct that.

Answer (score 12):

My two-cents worth, using more of a textual representation and an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{l@{\quad}cr@{}l}
    && y & {}= 2x+5 \\
    \text{minus} && y & {}= 3x+10 \\ \cline{2-4}
    && 0 & {}= -x-5
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}​
```

The additional (second) column is to allow for the `\cline` to have a little padding around the equations. Modify `\quad` to `\hspace{<len>}` to have a gap of length `<len>` between "minus" and the equation.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution:
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
    &y&=&&2x&&+&5\\   
    -\hspace*{.5em}&y&=&&3x&&+&10\\[-2.5ex]\cline{2-8}\\[-4.8ex]
    &0&=&&-x&&-&5    
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

I use the `alignat` enviroment from `amsmath`

Comment: Good one. Your spacing around the `=` on the second line is wrong. try removing the first `&` on each line. Hmmmm, on second thought, the location of the minus sign means "negative y", not minus the entire equation...

Comment: I already noted the problem. and posted the corrected version. thx ;)

Comment: Actually you should just use a single `&` to get the proper math spacing. Still there is a problem with the meaning of "minus y", which is not the OP's intent.

Comment: Yeah ok. I fixed it... But I'm not sure what russjohnson09 would like to see

Answer (score 1):

Stealing the idea with `\frac` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137587/19356) but replacing the `matrix` with `aligned`. Is it a cute idea? I hope so!

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\[
    \frac
    {
        \!\begin{aligned} 
                y &=    2x+5\\ 
                y   &=  3x+10 
        \end{aligned}
    }
    {0=-x-5}
    \ -
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I write it like this:

```
\[\frac{\begin{matrix} y=2x+5\\ y=3x+10 \end{matrix}}{0=-x-5}\ -\]
```