# Equations and defining equation variables

Tags: spacing, equations, numbering, align

I have a main equation that should be numbered and now I want to define the variables of the equations which may contain another set of equations. For example please have a look;

**code:**

```
\begin{align}
\label{eq:2.1}
&\frac{J_1(a k s)}{\sqrt{\pi } s}
\end{align}
\begin{align*}
\text{where} ~& \text{\textsl{a} is lens radius}\\
& \textsl{k}=\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }\\
& \textsl{s}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{u}{z_2}+\frac{x}{z_1}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{v}{z_2}+\frac{y}{z_1}\right){}^2}
\end{align*}
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

As we can see there is more than 2 line spacing (white space ) between the Eqn 2.1 and the variable definitions ... is there any other efficient way to define variables of equations without numbering them ... Or sub equation them as 2.1.1 , 2.1.2 etc ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:2.1}
\frac{J_1(a k s)}{\sqrt{\pi } s}\\
\intertext{where $a$ is lens radius}
\begin{aligned}
k &=\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }\\
s &=\sqrt{\left(\frac{u}{z_2}+\frac{x}{z_1}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{v}{z_2}+\frac{y}{z_1}\right){}^2}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

### Option 2:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:2.1}
\frac{J_1(a k s)}{\sqrt{\pi } s}\\
\begin{aligned}
\text{where } &a \text{ is lens radius}\\
&k =\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }\\
&s =\sqrt{\left(\frac{u}{z_2}+\frac{x}{z_1}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{v}{z_2}+\frac{y}{z_1}\right){}^2}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

### Option 3:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:2.1}
\frac{J_1(a k s)}{\sqrt{\pi } s}\\
\intertext{where}
\begin{aligned}
&a \text{ is lens radius}\\
&k =\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }\\
&s =\sqrt{\left(\frac{u}{z_2}+\frac{x}{z_1}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{v}{z_2}+\frac{y}{z_1}\right){}^2}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

### Option 4:

Using `\shortintertext` (Peter Grill's idea):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}\label{eq:2.1}
\frac{J_1(a k s)}{\sqrt{\pi } s}\\
\shortintertext{where}
\begin{aligned}
&a \text{ is lens radius}\\
&k =\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }\\
&s =\sqrt{\left(\frac{u}{z_2}+\frac{x}{z_1}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{v}{z_2}+\frac{y}{z_1}\right){}^2}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

The difference between `\intertext` and `\shortintertext`:

[image]

Comment: yeah the same issue, what if we want the text : a is lens radius and the other two variables K and S to be aligned one below the other. So that it looks neat and all the variables aligned one below the other in uniformity.

Comment: This also looks very helpful ... thanks a lot again ...

Comment: There is also `\shortintertext` from the `mathtools` package which has less vertical spacing, an example of which is in [How to subtract two equations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43102/how-to-subtract-two-equations/).

Answer (score 7):

As detailed in [align vs equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation) there are some occasions when the `equation` environment is more appropriate

[image]

I have moved your `\text{...}` into text mode in between the `equation` and `align` environment.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: true, trace: true}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2.1}
    \frac{J_1(a k s)}{\sqrt{\pi } s}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is lens radius
\begin{align*}
      & k=\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }                                                                      \\
      & s=\sqrt{\left(\frac{u}{z_2}+\frac{x}{z_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{v}{z_2}+\frac{y}{z_1}\right)^2} 
\end{align*}
```

or else (following the comment)

[image: screenshot]

```
where 
\begin{align*}
      & a\text{ is lens radius}                                                                        \\
      & k=\frac{2 \pi }{\lambda }                                                                      \\
      & s=\sqrt{\left(\frac{u}{z_2}+\frac{x}{z_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{v}{z_2}+\frac{y}{z_1}\right)^2} 
\end{align*}                

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks nice, but what if we want the text : a is lens radius and the other two variables K and S to be aligned one below the other.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari see the update :)